# Cannot change window size and position between hide and show

Tags: wpf, resize, window, flicker, sizetocontent

In my scenario I have a window which I want to use to display on two different ways. One way when the window has `WindowState = WindowState.Normal;` and the other way where the window has Normal or Maximised state.
I want to save the Size and Position of these two window modes so for the user it would seem like two separate windows.

I have two different issues around this.

1) When I initialize the window after Show() has been called, there is a small flicker which on slower machines isn't such a short flicker. In order to fix this I wanted to set up the window while it is hidden like so:

```
            ((SecondWindowViewModel)this.DataContext).LoadWindowPosition(mode);
            this.Show();
```

if I do this an even worst problem comes up

2)In this case window 1 which is in normal mode has some random height set on drag after window 2 has been closed in Maximized mode.

I've created a sample application what you can find [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=69BFDBD143F5C4E5!29462&authkey=!ABunKNdWpuLuUhw&ithint=folder%2csln), where you can see the exact problem, I've also written down the steps to reproduce as well.

**EDIT**

Implemented Maxims Changes and removed unnecessary references

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had yet the time to completely solve your issue, but one issue you have in your code is that you do not set the window state accordingly to your mode. In SecondWindow.xaml.cs, your code should look like this:

```
        if (mode == WindowViewMode.Normal)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }

        if (this.IsVisible)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            ((SecondWindowViewModel)this.DataContext).LoadWindowPosition(mode);
            this.Show();

        }
```

Still need to take a look at the problems your LoadWindowPosition is causing.

Comment: Hi Maxime! Thanks for pointing this out, but unfortunately this doesn't contribute to the bug in any way. But I've fixed that and also removed some unnecessary devexpress references and reuploaded the project.